# How to check if there are some new rows in table per minute?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS Windows service which checks some conditions and when the conditions are met, it sends email. Everytime the email is send, the time is stored in MSSQL Server 2008 in some table and in column "date" (format: 2013-03-02 09:33:21.853).

This service often doesn't work optimally and then it sends tens of e-mails per minute. (Normally 1-3 emails/minute). **I need sql script to check the amount of new rows in last minute.** Sorry if similar question is already here, I can not find it. And thank you for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Datediff()` function:

```
--To make it accurate to the milliseconds you could do
--datediff(millisecond, yourDateCol, getdate()) <=60*1000

Select count(*)
from yourTable
where datediff(second, yourDateCol, getdate()) <=60
```

Comment: Perfect. I decide to use minute instead of second. If someone is interesting in how to write the count of rows to variable here is the one-liner: $rows = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "10.10.0.2" -Database "YourDatabase" -Query "SELECT count(*) FROM YourTable WHERE datediff(minute, yourDateCol, getdate()) <= 1).Column1

Comment: Using `DATEADD()` function instead of `DATEDIFF()` can get milliseconds precision even when used with minutes:  
`WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,1,YourDateCol) > GETDATE()`

Comment: @culter: I would not recommend you to use `minute` because it would not give you accurate count. [Check this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22794) difference is only 10 seconds yet it returns 1

Comment: @culter Note that your changed version will NOT get rows within LAST minute, but rows from PREVIOUS minute. In example if current getdate() is 11:03:45... you will get record from 11:02:00 to 11:02:59.. and not those from 11:03:00 to 11:03:45

Comment: Thanks for your advices, guys. I don't need this precision. When the service is not working properly, it sends amounts of mail every minute. The difference is so huge, that I can reliably know that something is wrong. The script will be running every minute, so it's not so important if I restart the service one minute later. Anyway, you're right. Thank you!